# Maven can't find JavaFX

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, openjfx

Build Failure on Maven:
package javafx.application does not exist

I'm using JDK 8 because JDK 11 doesn't have JavaFX included by default.

I have openjfx listed in my pom file as a dependency.

I have `JAVA_HOME` set to:

```
$JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64: Is a directory
```

Is there an environment variable that needs to be set in order for Maven to find the JavaFX jars?

here is the terminal output and pom file

[image]

Comment: You say you're using JDK 8 because JDK 11 doesn't include JavaFX. But you appear to be using Linux and OpenJDK 8 which never included JavaFX, as far as I know. On top of that, you're trying to use OpenJFX **11** with Java **8**; that's not going to work.

Comment: Go for JDK 11 and follow the instructions here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use files compiled for version 54  (which is Java 10 according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) and the Java 8 you are using does not understand any higher versions than 52.

You cannot use this javafx-base artifact with Java 8.  Either revise your code or upgrade to at least Java 10.

Answer (score 0):

Your Maven still use JDK 11.

Try Oracle JDK 8 for Linux https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html or you can install from software repos in Linux.

Try to remove, uninstall all things of JDK 11 (then check environment variables carefully, checking by command `java -version` and `javac -version` to be sure you are using JDK 8).

Clean (`mvn clean`) and re-build project.